# Heterogeneous collection

Tags: c++, swift, hashset

In the new versions of C++, you can check if an item is in a `unordered_set` (a HashSet), even if that item is not the same type as the `unordered_set`, whilst maintaining O(1) time complexity.

**I'm trying to find out how to do this in Swift.**

Here is the C++ example:

```
struct First {
    int data;
    std::string otherData;

    First(int data, std::string otherData) : data(data), otherData(otherData) { }
};
struct Second {
    int data;
    int otherData;

    Second(int data, int otherData) : data(data), otherData(otherData) { }
};
```

Suppose I want to create an `unordered_set` of `First`, but I want to check if a `Second` object is in the `Set`, comparing by its `data` field. You could do this:

```
struct Equal {
    using is_transparent = void;

    template<class F, class S>
    bool operator()(const F& lhs, const S& rhs) const {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data;
    }
};

struct Hash {
    using is_transparent = void;

    template<class T>
    size_t operator()(const T& t) const {
        return std::hash<int>{}(t.data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<First, Hash, Equal> set;
    set.insert(First(100, "test"));

    std::cout << set.contains(First(100, "bla")) << "\n"; // true
    std::cout << set.contains(Second(100, 1000)) << "\n"; // true
}
```

And this works great. However, I'm not sure how you would achieve this in Swift. In Swift, a `Set` is the same thing as `unordered_set`, but its [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1540013-contains) method only accepts that specific element (no overloads).

You could iterate through all the elements, but you lose the O(1) HashSet time complexity.

I was wondering, is this possible in Swift?

Comment: You could roll your own function that first try convert the object to `ArrayLiteralElement`, and then use `contains` if that succeeds

Comment: You can't have `First` and `Second` in the same `Set` in Swift, unfortunately. You will either: 1) Have to make `First` and `Second` the same data type, where `otherData` is of type `Any` (or an enum case, such as `.int(...)` and `.string(...)`). 2) Only put `data` in the set. If possible, 2 is the better option. If not possible, I would go with an enum where each case stores the values needed, which differ between `First` and `Second`. I can write up an answer, if you would like (and you say which method you would prefer).

Comment: I believe it's [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fc6f9e0815c29909b049cbd92f59621e976ce42d/stdlib/public/core/NativeSet.swift#L161) in Swift's source code where they (privately) access part of the set with an element's `hashValue`. It would be very useful to be able to directly check if an element is in the set from a `hashValue`, because then this problem would be solvable without needing to change your data structures to something a bit less logical.

Comment: @George In a hash table, you can't directly get a value using just the hash code alone (there could be collisions). Thats why you also need to implement `Equatable` for the element, but unfortunately `Equatable` only works with the same type (I think)

Comment: @George I was also thinking maybe to use an `enum` for the entire class, so the enum has 2 values, First and Second, and it still maintains its value schematics

Comment: @whatisgoingon I forgot to add an answer for this - I'll do one now.

Answer (score 1):

To meet the basic requirement (partial matching), you can use [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2295403-contains) with a predicate to compare the hash values of elements to the hash of the target.

```
class First:Hashable {
    var data:Int;
    var otherData:String;

    static func == (lhs:First, rhs:First) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data;
    }
    
    init(data:Int, otherData:String) {
        self.data = data;
        self.otherData = otherData;
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(data)
    }
};

class Second:Hashable {
    var data:Int;
    var otherData:Int;

    static func == (lhs:Second, rhs:Second) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data;
    }

    init(data:Int, otherData:Int) {
        self.data = data;
        self.otherData = otherData;
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(data)
    }
};

var set: Set = [First(data: 100, otherData: "test")];
print(set.contains(First(data: 100, otherData: "bla")));

var hasher = Hasher();
Second(data: 100, otherData: 1000).hash(into:&hasher);
var target = hasher.finalize();

print(set.contains(where: {(candidate:First) -> Bool in
                       var hasher = Hasher();
                       candidate.hash(into:&hasher);
                       return hasher.finalize() == target;
                   }));
```

To meet the performance requirement, there are (at least) two options: refactor the hashable data to a common base class, or write an extension method that creates a temporary element of the appropriate type with the hashable data.

Moving the hashable data to a base class is the most straight-forward, though the resultant `Set` will only be homogenous in the base class. Also, this approach can't be implemented if you don't have control over the source of the element classes.

Once the classes are defined, `Set.contains(_:)` will work as desired.

```
class Zeroth:Hashable {
    var data:Int;

    static func == (lhs:Zeroth, rhs:Zeroth) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data;
    }
    
    init(_ data:Int) {
        self.data = data;
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(data)
    }
};

class First:Zeroth {
    var otherData:String;

    init(data:Int, otherData:String) {
        self.otherData = otherData;
        super.init(data)
    }
};

class Second:Zeroth {
    var otherData:Int;

    init(data:Int, otherData:Int) {
        self.otherData = otherData;
        super.init(data)
    }
};

var test = First(data: 100, otherData: "test");
var bla = First(data: 100, otherData: "bla");

var set: Set<Zeroth> = [test];
print(set.contains(bla));


var member = Second(data: 100, otherData: 1000);

print(set.contains(member));
```

An extension method gets the closest to the C++ interface. Use a protocol so the extension method can be constrained to classes that only hash some of their data. The protocol used below also adds a method, `partialCopy(from:)`, that handles converting between classes.

```
protocol DataElement {
    var data:Int {get}
    init(_ data:Int)
    static func partialCopy<Other:DataElement>(from other:Other) -> Self;
}

extension DataElement {
    static func partialCopy<Other:DataElement>(from other:Other) -> Self {
        return Self(other.data);
    }
}

class First:Hashable, DataElement {
    var data:Int;
    var otherData:String = "";

    static func == (lhs:First, rhs:First) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data;
    }

    required init(_ data:Int) {
        self.data = data;
    }
    
    init(data:Int, otherData:String) {
        self.data = data;
        self.otherData = otherData;
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(data)
    }
};

class Second:Hashable, DataElement {
    var data:Int;
    var otherData:Int = 0;

    static func == (lhs:Second, rhs:Second) -> Bool {
        return lhs.data == rhs.data;
    }

    required init(_ data:Int) {
        self.data = data;
    }
    
    init(data:Int, otherData:Int) {
        self.data = data;
        self.otherData = otherData;
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(data)
    }
};

var test = First(data: 100, otherData: "test");
var bla = First(data: 100, otherData: "bla");

var set: Set<First> = [test];
print(set.contains(bla));


extension Set where Element:DataElement {
    func contains<Other:DataElement>(matching member:Other) -> Bool {
        let matching : Element = Element.partialCopy(from:member); //Element(member.data);
        return self.contains(matching);
    }
}

var other = Second(data: 100, otherData: 1000);
print(set.contains(matching:other));
```

Comment: However you lose the O(1) time complexity of `Set`

Comment: @whatisgoingon: answer updated to match updated question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method #1

You can use an enum to store `First` and `Second` in the same set. You will have a case for `First` and a case for `Second`.

In the `Hashable` conformance for the enum, you should hash the data which is the same between both structs. The `Equatable` conformance just makes sure that if the hashes are equal, they are equivalent, even if the enum case is different.

Example:

```swift
enum Both: Hashable {
    case first(First)
    case second(Second)

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        switch self {
        case .first(let first):
            hasher.combine(first.data)
        case .second(let second):
            hasher.combine(second.data)
        }
    }

    static func == (lhs: Both, rhs: Both) -> Bool {
        lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}
```

```swift
struct First {
    let data: Int
    let otherData: String
}

struct Second {
    let data: Int
    let otherData: Int
}
```

```swift
let set: Set<Both> = [.first(First(data: 100, otherData: "test"))]

let first = First(data: 100, otherData: "bla")
print(set.contains(.first(first))) // true

let second = Second(data: 100, otherData: 1000)
print(set.contains(.second(second))) // true
```

---

#### Method #2

This may not be possible, if `First` and `Second` must be a struct. However, if they don't, you can have a superclass that does the `Hashable` conformance.

Example:

```swift
class Superclass: Hashable {
    let data: Int

    init(data: Int) {
        self.data = data
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(data)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Superclass, rhs: Superclass) -> Bool {
        lhs.data == rhs.data
    }
}
```

```swift
class First: Superclass {
    let otherData: String

    init(data: Int, otherData: String) {
        self.otherData = otherData
        super.init(data: data)
    }
}

class Second: Superclass {
    let otherData: Int

    init(data: Int, otherData: Int) {
        self.otherData = otherData
        super.init(data: data)
    }
}
```

```swift
let set: Set<Superclass> = [First(data: 100, otherData: "test")]

let first = First(data: 100, otherData: "bla")
print(set.contains(first)) // true

let second = Second(data: 100, otherData: 1000)
print(set.contains(second)) // true
```