# Observer pattern with protocols

Tags: swift, observer-pattern

I have a protocol `P` that has a `notify` function, and I'm kinda using it in a observer pattern.

Here is what I mean:

```
protocol P: AnyObject, Hashable {
  func notify()
}
extension P {
  // Compare by reference
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self))
  }
  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
  }
}
```

And I can have multiple listeners:

```
class Implemenation1: P {
  func notify() {
    print("Impl 1")
  }
}
class Implemenation2: P {
  func notify() {
    print("Impl 2")
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
var set: Set<P> = [Implemenation1(), Implemenation2()]
for x in set {
  x.notify()
}
```

However, I get an error saying

```
error: protocol 'P' as a type cannot conform to 'Hashable'
```

Is there any way to do the observer pattern?

Comment: Well, that was a [rabbit hole and then some](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4741) 

Comment: @MadProgrammer I answered a question along those lines recently, link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69121466/9607863)

Comment: @George Way to many hooks to solve something which should "just work" :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agreed. Hoping [SE-0309](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0309-unlock-existential-types-for-all-protocols.md) improves this, but I'm not entirely sure if this is what the proposal can solve.